# Proving $\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}$ is a norm

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove: $$\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}$$ is a norm in $C[a,b]$

1. $f^2(x)\geq 0$ so $\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}\geq 0$ and $\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}=0 \iff f(x)=0$
2. $\|c\cdot f\|=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}[cf(x)]^2dx}=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}c^2f^2(x)dx}=\sqrt{c^2\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}=\mid c\mid \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx}=\mid c\mid\cdot \|f\|$

Proving $\|f+g\|\leq \|f\|+\|g\|$ we need to use minkowski and holder inequalities?

Comment: In 1) you can only deduce that f=0 almost everywhere from the integral being zero

Comment: 1 and 2 look OK (in 1, $f$ is identically zero because $f \in C[a,b]$). For 3, if you have Minkowski's inequality, you can apply it (with $p=2$) and it gives the result immediately.

Comment: I will be suprise if this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

For the triangle part:
\begin{align}
\|f + g\|^2 = \int_a^b (f + g)^2 dx = \int_a^b (f^2 + 2fg + g^2) dx = \int_a^b f^2 dx + 2\int_a^b fg dx+ \int_a^b g^2 dx,
\end{align}
and note that $(\int_a^b (fg)^1 dx)^1 \leq \sqrt{\int_a^b f^2 dx} \sqrt{\int_a^b g^2 dx}$ by Holder's inequality with $p = q = 2$. Hence
\begin{align}
\|f + g \|^2 \leq \int_a^b f^2 dx + \int_a^b g^2 dx  + 2 \sqrt{\int_a^b f^2} \sqrt{\int_a^b g^2} = \left(\sqrt{\int_a^b f^2} +\sqrt{\int_a^b g^2} \right)^2 = (\|f\| + \|g\|)^2.
\end{align}
Now take square roots on both sides.